# When to use express.use, express.get, and express.post

Tags: node.js, express

What is the differences betwenn the 3 functions use/get/post with express?
In which case is better to use express.use instead of express.get/post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.use` is used to load the middleware functions.
app.use example:

```
var myUseFunction = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Hello World!');
  next();
}

app.use(myUseFunction);
```

It does not have limitations for any restful api http verbs like **POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE**.

`app.get` is route method is derived from one of the HTTP methods, and is attached to an instance of the express class.It serves the pupose of get request of apis.

**GET method route**

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('GET request to the page');
 });
```

`app.post` is route method is derived from of the HTTP methods, and is attached to an instance of the express class. It serves the pupose of post request of apis.

**POST method route**

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the page');
});
```

Comment: May you just better clarify when, from an operative point of view, it is better to use POST instead of GET? What are the bonus and malus by using each of them?

Answer (score 0):

`use` is for middleware, e.g., all requests. It says it right in the docs:

> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path.

`get` is... for GET requests. `post` is for POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

app.use is used to load the middleware functions to add some functionality in the middle before the execution of the next middleware or app.get function which is actually a route derived from HTTP method.
[image]